# New metric spaces from given one

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let (X,d) be a metric space, $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ continuous differentiable, strict monotone increasingly with $f(0)=0$ and a monotone decreasingly derivative.

Prove that $f \circ d$ is a metric on X as well.

I got problems with the triangle inequality. Any tips for me? (Pls no full solutions)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y>0$

$$f(x+y)-f(y)=\int _0^xf'(t+y)dt<\int_0^xf'(t)dt=f(x)-f(0)$$

as $f(0)=0$, $f$ is subadditive. So $$f(d(x,z))\le f(d(x,y)+d(y,z))\le f(d(x,y))+f(d(y,z)))$$

Answer (score 1):

You are defining $\rho(x,y)$ as $f(d(x,y))$. To prove the triangle inequality it suffices to prove that $f(a+b) \le f(a) + f(b)$ for any two positive numbers $a$ and $b$. But $$f(a+b) = \int_0^{a+b} f'(t) \, dt = \int_0^a f'(t) \, dt + \int_a^{a+b} f'(t) \, dt = f(a) + \int_0^b f'(t+a) \, dt.$$
Since $f'$ is monotone decreasing, $f'(t+a) \le f'(t)$ for all $t \ge 0$ so that $$\int_0^b f'(t+a) \, dt \le \int_0^b t'(t) \, dt = f(b).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).