# Proving inequality $ \frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|}\le \frac{|f(x)-h(x)|}{1+|f(x)-h(x)|}+\frac{|h(x)-g(x)|}{1+|h(x)-g(x)|} $

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose $f,g,h>0$ for every $x$. How can I show this inequality
$$
\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|}\le \frac{|f(x)-h(x)|}{1+|f(x)-h(x)|}+\frac{|h(x)-g(x)|}{1+|h(x)-g(x)|}
$$
Adding subtracting $h(x)$ to numerator is the way to go for numerator part but what about denominator?

Comment: Are you sure in the RHS of your inequality is a multiplication and not an addition ? (I strongly susêct that you want to prove that $d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ is a metric).

Comment: ... and that has been asked and answered many times before, e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/686792.

Comment: @Surb My bad man. Edited the question. Yeah I exactly want to prove that $d$ is metric

Comment: @MartinR The accepted answer over there is just stating the problem. I know what I have to show but how!

Comment: @FreeMind: Here is another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/981684 – you can find many more with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24d(x%2Cy)%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B%7Cx-y%7C%7D%7B1%2B%7Cx-y%7C%7D%24)